# Laravel multiple projects single package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

directory structure

```
   laravel package
    | |-project1
    |    |-app
    |    |-config
    |    |-resources
    | |-project2
    |    |-app
    |    |-config
    |    |-resources
    |-env
    | and other files
    |
```

i need the folder structure to be like above mentioned.please mention as tutorial as i am new to laravel. as i like to run multiple projects in the same laravel package without installing a new package sharing other files like env ,vendor etc.,

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

You can namespace all files under the app folder and prefix everything with 'project1', 'project2', etc

```
App/Project1/Models/etc...
App/Project1/Controllers/etc...

App/Project2/Models/etc...
App/Project2/Controllers/etc...
```

And in your route files, connect the routes to the different namespaces:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Project1\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

You can even make different route files for different projects and load them through the RouteServiceProvider@map method...

But to be honest, I would never go this way. Laravel is so easy to load through composer, what is the problem? The whole system runs so smoothly, why try to introduce these dimensions? But if you really want to, there is always a way... :-)